How to make IntelliJ stop putting the opening parentheses on the same line as my JSX?
Somewhere in the settings that IntelliJ has, there is something that I dislike. It transforms this code (in a .tsx file):
    return (
        <header className="flex items-center justify-between divide-x-2">
            <div/>
            <b>Name</b>
            <b>Model</b>
            <b>Capacity</b>
        </header>
    );

into:
    return (<header className="flex items-center justify-between divide-x-2">
        <div/>
        <b>Name</b>
        <b>Model</b>
        <b>Capacity</b>
    </header>);

How can I prevent IntelliJ, or WebStorm (as it's the same settings anyway), to format this TSX/JSX within parentheses?
I'm not using Prettier, nor any plugin of the sort.

Please try opening Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript and check the
Keep when reformatting | Line breaks option in the Wrapping and Braces tab. Does it help?
